# Tela fica desorganizada ao executar

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Estou com um problema, estou começando na programação android!

Já havia começado a um tempo e parei pelo mesmo motivo que estou tendo agora: meu computador não é muito bom e meio que não aceita o Emulador do Android Studio. Então o optei por usar o meu celular como Emulador.

Até ai tudo bem, mas eu faço tudo certo no Android Studio e o Previewer lá mostra que estudo centralizado e esta tudo correto, mas quando Emulo fica dessa maneira abaixo.

Alguém poderia me explicar ou me dar uma dica do que seja?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textView" 
    android:layout_width="279dp" 
    android:layout_height="61dp" 
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:text="@string/cabecalhot_texto" 
    android:textSize="24sp" 
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="53dp" 
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="57dp" /> 

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/botaoiniciarid" 
    android:layout_width="368dp" 
    android:layout_height="48dp" 
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:text="@string/botao_iniciar" 
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" 
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="268dp" /> 

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/resultadoid" 
    android:layout_width="368dp" 
    android:layout_height="35dp" 
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:text="@string/texto_numero" 
    android:textSize="18sp" 
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" 
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="415dp" />
```

Comment: Para podermos saber o que pode estar errado é necessário conhecermos o código que produz essa tela.

Comment: Você precisa postar o XML da Activity.

Comment: Ok acabei de adicionar o Codigo é algo basico so pra entender o porque quando faço a emulaçao aparece dessa forma! Obrigado

Comment: Colega, já que está aprendendo, inicie com o Relative Layout. Caso queira continuar com esse Layout então vai precisar estudar um pouco mais, porque ele é bem mais complicado e não é só colocar as coisas no lugar que você acha que ele vai ficar, isso só funciona no Relative.

Comment: Não coloque código como imagem, e o código do layout na versão de texto está incompleto face à imagem.

Comment: Quando se usa o Constraint-Layout é preciso fazer ligações que servem como referência de posicionamento na tela, como você não fez nenhuma marcação, então foi levado em consideração o padrão, que é ligar direto ao objeto pai. Esse tipo de gerenciador de layout é realmente difícil de manipular, aconselho usar o Linear-layout, pelo menos até pegar o jeito, dica de quem também está aprendendo e já passou por isso.

Comment: Não posso colar o código porque sou novo ai impede de usar vários Links

Comment: Mais, Obrigado vou ver se resolvo agora com as dicas ! ..

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que dizer a cada view sua posição em relação a outra view, exemplo se no Button você adicionar o atributo android:layout_below="@id/textView", você esta dizendo ao Button "fique abaixo da view de id textView".

veja este site!
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout#RelativePositioning